# What function does R implicitly call to print the return value of an expression?

Tags: r, output

When I type an expression into the R prompt, the result is normally printed to the terminal, unless something prevents it:

```
> 1+1
[1] 2
> 1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> invisible(1:10) # This prints nothing
```

I am trying to set up R to evaluate a bit of code immediately before printing anything. The obvious thing to do is to use `trace` to add an expression to the body of `print`. This has the expected effect when calling `print` explicitly, but not when simply evaluating an expression and letting it print automatically:

```
> trace(print, tracer = expression({cat("printing\n")}), print = FALSE)
> print(1:10) # Explicit print: trace code is executed
printing
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 1:10 # Implicit print: no trace
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So evidently R is not actually calling `print` when it simply wants to print the result of an expression, even though the result is the same as calling `print` explicitly. So what function *is* it calling, if any? Is there any function I can trace in place of `print` to make R evaluate my code prior to implicit printing?

---

If anyone is wondering, the code I actually want to execute is this function, which tells R the current terminal window width so it can use the full width when printing things:

```
get_terminal_width <- function() {
    cols <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))
    if (!is.na(cols)) {
        return(cols)
    }
    cols <- as.numeric(system2("tput", "cols", stdout = TRUE))
    if (!is.na(cols)) {
        return(cols)
    }
    return(NA_integer_)
}

update_width <- function(...) {
    try(options(width=as.character(get_terminal_width()-1)), silent = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: The comments in [print.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/print.c)  should be elucidating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about low level R behaviour that is governed by functionality that was coded in C, so you may struggle to capture and alter that behaviour in traditional R ( i.e. not compile your own version of R)
take a look at 1.6 : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html

Comment: The relevant line seems to be: "for objects without a class the internal code of print.default is called." I'm guessing "internal" means I won't be able to intercept it at the R level, even if I try tracing `print.default`. (And testing seems to confirm this.)

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the closest I can get is tracing `print` and `show`, which should cover S3 and S4 objects respectively.